# mySql query select

Tags: mysql, sql, database

1st table

```
GroupID MemberID    Name
  1        1        ---     
  1        23       ---     
  2        1        ---     
  2        23       ---     
  2        24       ---     
  3        1        ---     
  3        24       ---
```

2nd table

```
ID  MemberCount GroupName
1       2          ---
2       3          ---
3       2          ---
```

now I want to

```
select the GroupID where MemberID = (1 and 23) and MemberCount = 2
```

I'm using mySql and can't use intersect so how i can do this

Comment: `memberid in (1,23)`?

Comment: no it will select group id 1,2,3 because all have 1 or 23

Comment: oh. so you need users with BOTH of those ids? then `where memberid in (1,23) having count(memberid) = 2`, basically.

Comment: You need a query that merge the tables and then filters the result.

Comment: yes @MarcB ----

Comment: Google "[relational division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)" a.k.a. "the suppliers who supply all parts".

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.groupID 
FROM table1 a
, table2 b 
WHERE b.id = a.groupID 
AND b.MemberCount = 2 
AND a.MemberId in (1,23) 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(MemberId)) >= 2;
```

Comment: it's return 1,1,3 but i need 1

Answer (score 0):

This should work... I guessed the names.

```
SELECT g.id
FROM group g
WHERE g.membercount = 2
AND EXISTS ( SELECT null FROM user_group ug WHERE ug.groupid = g.id AND ug.memberid = 1 )
AND EXISTS ( SELECT null FROM user_group ug WHERE ug.groupid = g.id AND ug.memberid = 23 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select GroupID from table1 inner join table2 on table1.GroupID=table2.ID where MemberCount=2 and MemberID in (1,23);
```

Comment: this query return only 1

Comment: The IN operator takes a comma separated list of values, in your answer the "1 and 23" would be treated as an expression which results in the answer 1 - so the final part of your query is essentially "MemberID in (1)". This results in the query returning both 1 & 3 - not just 1.

Comment: sorry just a simple mistake

Comment: can i send the screenshot of my output?

Comment: It's the simple mistakes that are hard to find & often cause the biggest problems. Now you have edited it - your answer is essentially the same as the one given by sonnenhohl (prior to the "having(count)" edit) that has already been determined as wrong - have you actually tested this answer. If you check the documentation you will find that the IN operator is a short hand for OR, so the query will return the results for each row with MemberID equal to 1 or 23 - so the result will be 1,1,3.

Comment: but my query in mysql gives only 1 i dont know what wrong with this

Comment: @Prashant Kumar Singh

Comment: Did you look at the sqlfiddle I gave a link to which shows the result using your query

Comment: its gives unable to connect